Entity stream is closed in ContainerResponseFilter
I am trying to capture the request body string using entity stream in both request filter and response filter. But when I try to fetch request body string entity stream in the response filter, I get the entity stream closed exception. Is there a way where I can use the entity stream in the response filter. Basically, I want to get the request string in both request and response filter. Any help is appreciated
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        InputStream entityStream = requestContext.getEntityStream();
        byte[] entityBytes = entityStream.readAllBytes();
        String requestBody = new String(entityBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        InputStream entityStream = requestContext.getEntityStream(); //This throws entity close exception. I need request in response filter
}


Why do you use JAX-RS in Spring Boot?

This is a legacy code base and had to add some code based on the request in the response filter.
